# Drag and drop between ExtJS tree panels with preloadChildren false

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

I have two panels that get dynamically loaded. I need to drag and drop between them. The problem is that once I drag and drop an unexpanded node it doesn't get copied completely... just the node, not it's subtree (children). I don't what it expended in the first place because it kills the performance... I need to copy it unexpanded. Could that be done?

PS: Using ExtJS 4.1.

Comment: share some more information such as your own code, what else have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/tree/two-trees.html) example by Sencha. This might be useful.